# Let $f:\mathbb{R}_n\to\mathbb{R}_m$ be continuous and $\lim_{|x|\to \infty}|f(x)|=\infty$. Then $f(\mathbb{R}_n)$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}_m$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}_n\to \mathbb{R}_m$ be continuous and $\lim_{|x|\to \infty}|f(x)| = \infty$. Show that $f(\mathbb{R}_n)$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}_m.$

Actually I know that $f$ has a minimum value, but how can I prove the image is closed?

Comment: Use the fact that the continuous image of a compact set is compact.

Comment: But Rn is open and closed, it is not a compact set.

Answer (score 0):

We will use the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem in the proof. Let $y \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ be a limit point of the image. So there are points $\{y_{i}\}_{i=1}^{n}$ such that $\lim_{i\to \infty} y_{i} = y$ and $y_{i}$ lie in the image. Let $y_{i} = f(x_{i})$.

We claim that $x_{i}$ must be bounded. If not there is a subsequence $\{x_{i_{k}}\}$of $x_{i}$ which goes to $\infty$. Then $\{y_{i_{k}}\}$ must also diverge to $\infty$. But that isn't true since $\{y_{i_{k}}\}$ converge to $y$. Hence $x_{i}$ are bonded.

By Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, there is a convergent subsequence $\{x_{i_{k}}\}$ of $\{x_{i}\}$. Let $\lim_{k\to \infty} x_{i_{k}} = x$. Then by continuity of $f$, $\lim_{k \to \infty} f(x_{i_{k}}) = f(x)$, therefore $\lim_{k\to \infty} y_{i_{k}} = f(x)$. But $y_{i_{k}}$ converge to $y$. Therefore $f(x) = y$. Hence $y$ is also in the image. Therefore the image of $f$ is closed.